# Infinite base two number to base ten

Tags: binary, number-bases

Suppose I have a base two number that repeats itself every five places (a number $x$ such that $0\le x<1$. For example:

$$x=0.101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101...$$

What would be a cool way to start with:

```
x={1,0,1,0,1}
```

Then, thinking of this five number list as repeating itself forever, use *Mathematica* to change it to a base 10 number.

**Update:** My question came as a result of @Kagaratsch's answer at [Using a piecewise defined sequence, find all $x_0$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101282/using-a-piecewise-defined-sequence-find-all-x-0). Thanks to @Xavier's answer, now I can do this:

```
mytup = Tuples[{0, 1}, 5]
FromDigits[{{#}, 0}, 2] & /@ Most[mytup]
```

Comment: `{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}. (2)^Range[0, 4]/(2^5 - 1) //N`

Comment: `NSum[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}.  (2)^-Range[n + 1, n + 5], {n, 0, Infinity, 5}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2 better still, your expression with plain `Sum` produces the exact `21/31` result.

Comment: @george2079 Yeah, I realized that, but I thought the question asked for numerical, decimal result.  I suppose `RealDigits@Sum[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}. (2)^-Range[n + 1, n + 5], {n, 0, Infinity, 5}]` or `{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}. (2)^Range[0, 4]/(2^5 - 1) // RealDigits` might be more in line with @David's question.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
FromDigits[{{{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}}, 0}, 2]
```

where `{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}` is the infinite repeating part, `0` the length of the integer part, and `2` the base in which the number is given. The output will be given in base ten.

```
FromDigits[{{{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}}, 0}, 2]
(* 21/31 *)
```

Comment: Wow! Haven't seen this one before. Thanks.

Comment: See my update to my original post. Thanks to you, I found this idea in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It should be clear that if x = 0.101011010110101....  then 2^5 x = 10101.1010110101... so 32 x - x = 10101 = 21, then x = 21/31.